# Where in Rails App should I be creating a JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a rails app with two steps:

1) form where user selects options

2) result table where user sees output based on options in 1

Right now, the result table is built with datatables.  The table is populated in the view by iterating through the options passed in from step 1 with the model being called for each row in tr's and td's.  I suspect there is a better way to do this.

I want to format the table to output to PDF with nice formatting, and most of the examples I see online involve JSON data being passed in.  Should I have my model or controller create this JSON object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to output the result to a PDF, you don't need JSON data being passed, you can use prawn pdf [prawnpdf gem](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn), and you can use same method from your statement "The table is populated in the view by iterating through the options passed", you just need to split the output with  **respond_to** format

```
@your_data_tables = YourOptionModel....
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    pdf = ReportPdf.new(@your_data_tables) 
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "your_data_table.pdf",type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
  end
end
```

here is sample to split output between html and pdf using respond_to